# "Condition is always 'true'" and "Array index is out of bounds" warnings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to develop my first android app using android studio, and am getting a couple of warnings I can't seem to get rid of in an inner class constructor:

1. In the for loop it warns that the termination condition is always true. However this wanring only shows for the inner `col` for loop and not the outer `row` for loop.
2. In the assignment of `grid[row][col]`, it warns that the array index `[row]` is out of bounds, but not that the index `[col]` is.

I don't understand why the warnings are appearing at all, given the code seems to run as intended, but also why the warnings only appear for one for loop and one index, when surely any problem would also apply to the other? Any help is much appreciated!

---

```
private class MyInnerClass {
    private final Character UNKNOWN = '.';

    // State data
    private String id;
    private Integer grid_size;
    private final Character[][] grid;

    // Constructor
    public MyInnerClass(String id, Integer grid_size) {
        // Check the grid size is in the permitted range
        String[] permitted_grid_sizes = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.permitted_grid_sizes);
        int min_permitted_grid_size = Integer
                .parseInt(permitted_grid_sizes[0]);
        int max_permitted_grid_size = Integer
                .parseInt(permitted_grid_sizes[permitted_grid_sizes.length - 1]);
        if ((grid_size < min_permitted_grid_size) || (grid_size > max_permitted_grid_size)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "specified grid size (" + grid_size + ") out of range");
        }

        // Initialise metadata
        this.id = id;
        this.grid_size = grid_size;

        // Initialise a blank grid
        this.grid = new Character[this.grid_size][this.grid_size];
        for (int row = 0; row < this.grid_size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.grid_size; col++) {        // Gives warning "Condition 'col < this.grid_size' is always 'true'"
                this.grid[row][col] = UNKNOWN;                      // Gives warning "Array index is out of bounds" on [row]
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Does the problem persist when you restart Android Studio? At first glance, it seems like it's a problem on their end

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Android Studio. Changing the field `grid_size` from `private Integer grid_size;` to `private int grid_size;` removes the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to variable typing.
The field `grid_size` is of class Integer and you are comparing it with `row` and `col` which are of primitive type 'int'.

`grid_size == row` compares a reference to a value.

What's probably happening is that your IDE is detecting this problem but giving you inaccurate warnings.

If you change `grid_size` to primitive type `int`, the warnings should go away.